# Плеер играет один и тот же канал при одинаковом url, но с разными портами

Tags: android, mediaplayer, port

Плеер не может воспроизвести потоки с одного адреса, но с разных портов, все время показывает один и тот же канал. Иногда переключается на другой, но потом уже будет этот "другой" канал по всем остальным показывать

*Адреса, например:*

https://url:5050/channel-id/index.m3u8,

https://url:5253/channel-id/index.m3u8,

https://url:5583/channel-id/index.m3u8

Такое только на смартфонах и планшетах, а на приставке, телике и пк нормально распознают плееры порты.

На **медиа плеере**, **ijk**, **vlc** такая ситуация, а **exo** вообще отказывается показывать

Можно это как-то исправить или это особенность смартфонов и планшетов?

Если можно, то в какую сторону копать?